# File missing in git after messy merges and cherry-picks

Tags: git

I heavily messed up master (not the main one) and development branches of part of a project I'm responsible for, and then messed up again by using cherry-pick and force push to get a working release out instead of reverting. One of the things I did was to exclude some functionality that wasn't yet due for a release. Later I realised that this functionality is somehow missing from the development branch, but is present in my_master branch (it was merged into the main master by the lead developers).

The strange thing is I cannot find out how I deleted the code in the first place. There are some files missing from dev, and querying git log or git rev-list shows **nothing**. When I switch to the main branch, the files and commits show up as they should. I'd like to untangle this mess but I'm stumped.

How can this happen and is there a way to find out which commit deleted the file? It could have been a cherry-pick or a merge. I tried some answers from popular SO questions on the topic but none worked. It's as if the file was never in the dev branch to begin with, even though I can merge master into dev without any conflicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the history tooling inside `git log` is designed to help you locate the commit in which the code you see in the file version stored in the *latest* commit came from.  If the code *isn't* there, finding where something that *is* there, *didn't* go away from, does not help you find where something that *isn't* there, but *was* at one point, vanished.

The main trick here is to add `--full-history` to `git log` when looking for stuff that went missing.  This forces `git log` to track both "sides" of each merge, rather than simplifying away the side that *didn't* get used.

This does not work for a broken cherry-pick.  There's no easy way to have Git find a cherry-pick that was resolved incorrectly, because the only thing you find in the history is the commit itself, and all it shows you is what happened in that commit, not what (you or anyone else might think) could or should have happened.

Comment: One of my colleagues also told me that cherry-pick heavily messes up history, so I'm marking this as the correct answer. He advised me to rebuild the dev branch from master, which I did, since there wasn't that many changes at this point. Can't close the question, so might as well mark it answered.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that cherry-pick "messes up" history. It creates new commits, and history is nothing but commits: the commits *are* the history. So it creates new history that is sometimes hard to tell *from* old history (if you look at the contents of commits, rather than their hash IDs, and of course that's how *humans* work...). All of which means that cherry-picking has *limited* usefulness. It's good for some special cases, and it also is the way that `git rebase` actually works so it's good for that to the extent that you think `git rebase` is good. :-)